# A very unexpected problem in deleting an element from singly linked lists

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
void insertbeg(n*head)
{

    n *x,*q=head;
    q=(n*)malloc(sizeof(n));
    printf("Enter the data to be entered: ");
    scanf("%d",&q->data);
    q->link=NULL;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=q;
    }
    else
    {
        q->link=head;
        head=q;
    }
    x=head;
    while(x!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\t",x->data);
        x=x->link;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

This code runs as expected ,this is the function, the driver program intakes the actual list and once done calls this function .At the end it prints the output with a user entered element at the beginning all good till here . I have a series of switch cases where each case calls a function like insert element at the beginning, delete from end etc , but when I go for say any other option after any operation like delete from end , it deletes the last element and prints the result after operating on the actual and not on the modified list like for example: 
                             1 2 3 4 is the actual list
                             I choose to insert an element at the beginning .
                             after I insert say 7 ,it prints 7 1 2 3 4.
                             After that I choose to delete an element from end.
                             It prints 1 2 3.
                             ** but rather it should print 7 1 2 3 **
This happens with each case it performs the operation operates on the actual list and not on the modified list and prints the result.

Any help would be ,much appreciated .[Images of the actual driver program added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUCsK.png)

Comment: `n *head` and not `n*head` may be a typo ?

Comment: @Gaming DEITY Do not provide references to images. Provided the relevant code in your question. Otherwise your question will be down-voted.

Comment: Oops, you show us a working code, say that another part of the code does not work, but fail to show the problematic deleting code. As a new user you should read (again) ask, and think about what others need in a [mvce] to be able to reproduce the problem. Here we need a compilable example with the input exhibiting the problem.

Comment: @SergeBallesta The shown function is also invalid.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: I must admit that I blindly trusted OP when they said *The code runs as expected* and did not test it. But I really insist on a [mcve], and will not test without it.

Comment: Show how you delete your node

Comment: @Landstalker There is no typo. The variable head has the type  n *. That is it is a pointer to the head node of the list.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow  I wanted to say that it is not a preferable writing. `n *head` or `n* head` would be better.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Really sorry , being a new user I was not aware that providing reference to images is not allowed .

Comment: @SergeBallesta , see the code that i provided and all other codes including deleting ,inserting at end works fine but after performing a certain operation when i go for another operation it performs that operation on the original list and not on the modified list .

Answer (score 2):

For starters never provide references to images. All relevant code shall be typed and present in the question. Provide minimal demonstrative program that reproduces the problem.

I do not have any desire to see the image a reference to which you placed in your question but already the function `insertbeg` that as you think "works", is invalid. It deals with a copy of the pointer to the head node of the list. So this statement

```
head=q;
```

does not change the original pointer passed to the function as an argument. It changes a copy of the original pointer.

Pay attention that each function should do one think. If you want to oiutput the list then write one more function that will do the task.

Also the function has to get a data that will be added to the list as an argument.

It is better to pass the pointer by reference to the function.

The function can look the following way

```
int insertbeg( n **head, int data )
{
    n *q = malloc( sizeof( n ) );

    int success = q != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        q->data = data;
        q->link = *head;
        *head = q;
    }

    return success;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how functions that append a node to the beginning of the list and delete a node from its end can be defined.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *link;
} n;

int insert_in_begin( n **head, int data )
{
    n *q = malloc( sizeof( n ) );

    int success = q != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        q->data = data;
        q->link = *head;
        *head = q;
    }

    return success;
}

void delete_from_end( n **head )
{
    if ( *head != NULL )
    {
        while ( ( *head )->link != NULL ) head = &( *head )->link;

        free( *head );

        *head = NULL;
    }
}

void output( n *head )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->link )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", head->data );
    }

    puts( "null" );
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 10 };

    n *head = NULL;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        insert_in_begin( &head, i );
    }

    while ( head != NULL )
    {
        output( head );
        delete_from_end( &head );
    }

    output( head );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
9 -> 8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0 -> null
9 -> 8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> null
9 -> 8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> null
9 -> 8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> null
9 -> 8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> null
9 -> 8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> null
9 -> 8 -> 7 -> 6 -> null
9 -> 8 -> 7 -> null
9 -> 8 -> null
9 -> null
null
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the following lines:

```
head=q;
```

While the logic of what you are trying to do is solid the issue here is that you are changing the value of head on the stack. In other words what you receive in this function as a parameter is the address of the first element of the list. This address is put on the stack and you use it within the insertbeg function.

Now, what you need to do here is to somehow tell the code that is calling this function (I think you refer to it in the question as driver) that the head has changed. I think the best way to do this is to change the parameter from n* to n**.

That way you would receive the address of the pointer head and not just what it is pointing at (i.e. the address of the first element).

To sum up, I would suggest the following changes:

1) Change the parameter from `n*head` to `n **addressOfHead`

2) Change every occurrence of `head` in your code to `*addressOfHead`

A little explanation of what we just did there:

1) We now pass on the **address** of the variable that holds the address of the first element **instead** of the address of the first element itself. This way we can propagate the information about the new address of the first element back to the code that called the function.

2) Because of what we did in point 1 we don't have the head parameter anymore containing the address of the first element of the list. We can still get that address though by de-referencing the double pointer we have. Like this `*addressOfHead`. With this expression we basically tell the compiler "please give me the number that is in the memory-location addressOfHead". That number is the address of the first element (i.e. the head).

Hope, I could help.

Comment: @Gaming DEITY Don't be disheartened by bugs like this. IMHO pointers are a tricky thing to master. 

Try visualizing the variables involved. Try sketching the memory space for the driver and the function you call as separate areas and draw boxes for each variable (both pointer and regular). Then connect the pointers and the boxes they point at with arrows. Think about how the addresses are passed around by your code and redraw the arrows after each step. 

I know it sounds trivial (and tedious) but it helped me a lot to get a grip on pointers when I first met them :)

Comment: @Gaming DEITY Also this might help:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/double-pointer-pointer-pointer-c/

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed explanation sir , it helped me a lot to figure what was actually going wrong. @Istvan Balogh